# Which user-mode functions to hook to monitor/intercept file access?

Tags: c#, windows, hook

Which user-mode functions in Windows 7 can I hook to monitor/**intercept file access**?

I've tried ntdll.dll's `NtOpenFile()`, `NtCreateFile()`, but some of these aren't files - they're also pipes and mutexes. Same goes for kernel32.dll's `CreateFile()`. Is there a function that is called only to access files/directories. If it helps, I'm trying to only hook explorer.exe to prevent access to firefox.exe. I'm also using EasyHook, if any of you have familiarity with it.

I think I've also read somewhere that, using the parameters from NtOpenFile/NtCreateFile, you can distinguish between file access/pipe access. But that's still a bit hazy. Is there a nice comfortable function to hook?

EDIT: Please keep in mind I do need to **intercept file access** to prevent access to some files. EasyHook is a great solution, since it allows me to perform complicated hooking in a few easy steps in C# managed code.

Comment: Why can't you just change the permissions for the file you want to deny access to?

Comment: Not as elegant. I want the challenge and experience that comes with coding hooks.

Comment: In that case, write unmanaged code and do the hooking yourself. There's no challenge or experience in using a library for hooking.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "file open function" that only opens files. Furthermore, hooking is only supported using Detours. Finally, you must ensure that all computers running this have .NET 4.0 installed, so they can run in-proc SxS.

A far superior solution is to change the file permissions on firefox.exe. This is a solution that requires no licensing of Detours, and is supported.

Comment: Maybe changing file permissions will work, but it's definitely not as elegant and I enjoy the challenge. What do you mean by hooking is only supported by Detours? Detours is discontinued; EasyHook is a superior library.

Comment: What do you mean that Detours is discontinued? [It still listed on Microsoft's IP licensing page.](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/IntellectualProperty/IPLicensing/Programs/Detours.aspx). Most major OS upgrades include more protection against hooking programs (which are usually spyware or viruses). Microsoft won't hesitate to break EasyHook-based programs for security reasons, but they support Detours.

Comment: File permissions are the most elegant solution to the problem. Think about it: you wish to restrict access to a specific file. Um... file permissions are the most elegant solution. There is definitely a challenge to hooking (especially kernel code on x64), but a "challenge" is a horrible excuse to write horrible code.

Comment: And if they simply overwrote the file permissions again? Am I going to be polling the permission masks and overwriting them again with all Deny periodically?

Comment: Either the user owns the computer or not. If the user owns the computer, then it is their perrogative to change the file permissions, and no program should take that right away. If the user does not own the computer, then they should not be in the `Administrators` group and they simply don't have the permission to change the permissions on the file.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)

Comment: @theB: I'm quite sure Detours handles that situation.

Comment: @StephenCleary - That was aimed at the OP's comment: "Am I going to be polling the permission masks and overwriting them again with all Deny periodically?"